# Spring boot 1.5 tests don't roll back transaction

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm starting a simple Spring boot project + JPA + Hibernate + Mysql. Before starting coding I created some very simple tests but unfortunately the behaiour is not that expected. This is my test class:

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
@Transactional
public class TenantTest {

    @Autowired
    private TenantRepository tenantRepository;

    @Test
    public void createTenant() {
        Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
        tenant.setAddress("Street n.1");
        tenant.setAlias("tenant");
        tenant.setCity("Milan");
        tenant.setCountry("Italy");
        tenant.setEmail("info@email.com");
        tenant.setLandlinePhone("3902123456");
        tenant.setMobilePhone("39347123456");
        tenant.setName("Tenant 1");
        tenant.setType(TenantType.RESELLER);

        Tenant savedObj = tenantRepository.save(tenant);

        assertNotNull("Tenant null after save!", savedObj);

    }

    @Test
    public void createTenantWithInvalidEmail() {
        Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
        tenant.setAddress("Street n.1");
        tenant.setAlias("tenant");
        tenant.setCity("Milan");
        tenant.setCountry("Italy");
        tenant.setEmail("info@email");
        tenant.setLandlinePhone("3902123456");
        tenant.setMobilePhone("39347123456");
        tenant.setName("Tenant 1");
        tenant.setType(TenantType.RESELLER);

        Tenant savedObj = tenantRepository.save(tenant);

        assertNotNull("Tenant null after save!", savedObj);

    }
```

According to Spring documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testing-tx), each test should be rolled back. Instead in my example this doens't happen. In fact I've this error for the second test:

```
    org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_6xsyaq3xonk8dkjed1lmu31ve]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.server.TenantTest.createTenantWithInvalidEmail(TenantTest.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2909)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3480)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:626)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:765)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'tenant' for key 'UK_6xsyaq3xonk8dkjed1lmu31ve'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2501)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
    ... 80 more
```

This happens obviously because the transaction is not rolled back. I also printed debug log of spring and Spring is saying it is rolling back the transaction:

```
 017-06-06 18:29:12.683  INFO 7556 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@3f200884 testClass = TenantTest, testInstance = com.test.server.TenantTest@35fac3ba, testMethod = createTenant@TenantTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@4d339552 testClass = TenantTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.test.server.TestApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{classpath:test.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@5025a98f, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@192b07fd, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@520a3426], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@7d43f1c9]; rollback [true]
2017-06-06 18:29:12.753  INFO 7556 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@3f200884 testClass = TenantTest, testInstance = com.test.server.TenantTest@35fac3ba, testMethod = createTenant@TenantTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@4d339552 testClass = TenantTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.test.server.TestApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{classpath:test.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@5025a98f, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@192b07fd, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@520a3426], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
2017-06-06 18:29:12.756  INFO 7556 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@3f200884 testClass = TenantTest, testInstance = com.test.server.TenantTest@4c599679, testMethod = createTenantWithDuplicatedAlias@TenantTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@4d339552 testClass = TenantTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.test.server.TestApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{classpath:test.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@5025a98f, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@192b07fd, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@520a3426], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@7d43f1c9]; rollback [true]
2017-06-06 18:29:12.760  WARN 7556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2017-06-06 18:29:12.760 ERROR 7556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry 'tenant' for key 'UK_6xsyaq3xonk8dkjed1lmu31ve'
2017-06-06 18:29:12.764  INFO 7556 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@3f200884 testClass = TenantTest, testInstance = com.test.server.TenantTest@4c599679, testMethod = createTenantWithDuplicatedAlias@TenantTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@4d339552 testClass = TenantTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.test.server.TestApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{classpath:test.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@5025a98f, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@192b07fd, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@520a3426], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
```

Relevant part of my properties configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.database: mysql
spring.jpa.show-sql: false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.max_fetch_depth=3
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=150
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
```

I'm using the annotation @Transaction at level class. I don't see what is wrong with this configuration. Do you have some advice?

Comment: Try using the `MySQL5InnoDBDialect`. Also you either specify the `database-platform` or `database` but not both.

Comment: @M.Deinum I removed database property but was not that the problem. Using MySQL5InnoDBDialect it works! In my case I replaced with spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb because I'm usign Hibernate 5.2 and the value you suggested is deprecated. Please post your answer so I can confirm it. Also, do you have an idea why with InnoDB dialect works and without doesn't? Thanks

Comment: Add `@TransactionConfiguration` on your test class. Have a look at: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionConfiguration.html.

It is also mentioned that it is deprecated, and as of Spring Framework 4.2, use @Rollback or @Commit at the class level and the transactionManager qualifier in @Transactional.

Comment: Actually seems work fine only with MySQL5InnoDBDialect. I don't know why.

Comment: Because you are probably on a bit older MySQL version which defaults to tables of the MyISAM type which don't support transactions. Newer MySQL versions default to InnoDB. Using the `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` will force InnoDB tables and as such supports transactions.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm using Mysql 5.6.22-log on Windows.

Comment: Check the `my.cfg` the `default-storage-engine` is probably set to `MyISAM` (or maybe the windows version has a different default?). Or your startup script for mysql has `--default-storage-engine=myisam` or something like that.

Comment: Stange, the value is default-storage-engine=INNODB

Comment: Something must be triggering `MyISAM` for this instance of MySQL, which is the reason it doesn't work. Could be your startup script as well, or an environment setting or maybe `InnoDB` isn't supported on this MySQL version. (you can do `SHOW ENGINES` to get a list of supported engines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using MySQL version < 5.5.5 then the default storage engine is `MyISAM` which doesn't support transactions (or the `default-storage-engine` property in the `my.cfg` is set to `MyISAM`).

The storage engine that does support transactions is `InnoDB`.

Now you basically have 2 ways of solving this.

1. Upgrade MySQL to at least 5.5.5 (or even more recent)
2. Use the proper Hibernate Dialect

To specify the proper dialect you need to set the `spring.jpa.database-platform` to the correct class.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Setting this dialect will enforce the storage engine InnoDB.

**NOTE:** You should set either `spring.jpa.database-platform` or `spring.jpa.databse` but not both (as the latter will override the dialect!).

If you are using Hibernate 5.2.8 or up you can omit the `spring.jpa.database-platform` and only set the `spring.jpa.database` (or let it auto-detect) and set the `hibernate.dialect.storage_engine` property to `innodb`. (See also [this blog](http://in.relation.to/2017/02/20/mysql-dialect-refactoring/) on that).

```
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between committing a transaction and flushing / synchronizing your JPA persistence context. Flushing the peristence context writes the generated SQL to the database. This can happen at any time as determined by the persistence provider by mainly at transaction commit time. However it can also happen when you are using auto generated identifiers that are generated on the database side a.k.a IDENTITY or when executing queries.

So its possible for the ransaction to be rolled back even when the persistence context has been flushed.

Even the Spring log indicates that the test transaction is being rolled back. Try with a record that does not produce an exception and this should be rolled back as well

Comment: I got the point and that's very clear. Unfortunately also with 2 tests that don't produce exception, I found entries in the database (I changed the ddl-auto to create). So seems there is something else wrong.

Comment: Which PlatformTransactionManager is defined for you application context?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot just with annotations. I didn't define any PratformTransactionManager. So, my guess is used the default one.